# Pinescript Trading Strategy not following the long conditions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

I am trying to implement an ichimoku cloud strategy in conjunction with MACD.

What I am trying to do is to follow long conditions only when the ichimoku cloud turns green, i.e., when leading span A is above leading span B.

But the long entries are made irrespective of the above condition. Check screenshot.

[image]

Comment: please past your entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ichimoku is a lagging indicator. Those plots are displayed with an offset `offset = displacement - 1`. Therefore you should use the history reference operator `[]` in your conditions.

The below code will tell oyu if the cloud is green or not.

```
is_green_cloud = (leadLine1 > leadLine2)[displacement - 1]
```